# How to fetch JSON from a jsp page with Axios in Vue.js?

Tags: jsp, vue.js

I'm using a JSP page which gets data from a database table and converts it into a JSON string via GSON. This JSON is then fetched to the client side via Axios, and the data is displayed on the web page.

The problem is, that while the JSP can successfully create a JSON string from the fetched data from the database table (evident from Eclipse IDE console), I can't get the JSON data to the web page. I'm also getting a `TypeError: handler.call is not a function at invokeWithErrorHandling` and `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: handler.call is not a function" (found in <Root>)` in browser's console window.

Here's the JSP responsible for creating JSON string (array?):

```
while(rs.next()) {
    currUser.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    currUser.setDob(rs.getString("dob"));
    currUser.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
    currUser.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
    currUser.setState(rs.getString("state"));
    currUser.setReqCount(rs.getInt("reqcount"));
    currUser.setPostCount(rs.getInt("postcount"));
}

String reqCount = new String();
reqCount.valueOf(currUser.getReqCount());

String postCount = new String();
reqCount.valueOf(currUser.getPostCount());

final ArrayList<String> user= new ArrayList<String>();
user.add(currUser.getName());
user.add(currUser.getDob());
user.add(currUser.getCity());
user.add(currUser.getState());
user.add(reqCount);
user.add(postCount);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(user);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
response.sendRedirect("profile.html");
```

Here's the HTML code where the JSON data is supposed to show up:

```
<div v-for="items in profile">
    <p><strong>Name: <br /> {{profile.name}}</strong></p>
    <p>Date of Birth: {{profile.dob}}</p>
    <p>City: {{profile.city}}</p>
    <p>State: {{profile.state}}</p>
    <p>Volunteers requested: {{profile.postcount}} times</p>
    <p>Volunteered: {{profile.reqcount}} times</p>
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#main',

    data: {
        profile: [],
        name: '',
        dateOfBirth: '',
        state: '',
        city: '',
    },

    computed: {
        getProfileData: function () {
            axios.get("B_test.jsp")
            .then((response) => {
              this.profile = response.data.value;
            })
        }
    },
})
```

The `main` id is already defined further up in the code, so I know that I have a mountable element for Vue. I've also imported the Axios API via CDN, along with Vue's CDN.

The above code does not show anything from the div in the page, when in theory it should display the data from JSON (perhaps because there's nothing to compute for the `computed` hook), along with the two aforementioned warnings.

Apologies for any potential rookie mistakes, hope you'll bear with a first-timer like me.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. 1. You're using a JSP just to execute Java code. That's what servlets are for. 2. Your JSP writes JSON to the response, and then immediately after decides to redirect to another JSP (profile.jsp) after all. What's the point in generating JSON if, in the end, you tell the browser to ignore it and instead navigate to another page?

Comment: @JBNizet. I get the servlet preference, but there's nothing to be done about that. If possible, I'd like to use JSP as it is.
The original idea was to use the JSON generated from the JSP in the page where JSP redirects to. Are there any methods to call the JSON after its creation in JSP? Or perhaps there's an alternative solution?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what a redirect is. A redirect consists in setting the status of the response to 301 or 302, and to add a header asking the browser to ignore the response, and instead immediately make another request to "profile.html".

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the explanation about redirection. I've removed the redirection line, but the data isn't still fetched from the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think your use of v-for is incorrect...as per https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html and this example:

```
<ul id="v-for-object" class="demo">
  <li v-for="value in object">
    {{ value }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think you should say v-for="profile in items" and not "items in profile" . As for the get(), it is possible that you have a similar problem that I had recently where a similar method (fetch()) was returning promises that I had to wait before i tried to use...so perhaps when you do:

```
    .then((response) => {
      this.profile = response.data.value;
    })
```

Are you sure that response.data is available immediately? Perhaps the server takes some time to answer and the code is already trying to assign response.data.value but it's not ready yet. The way my problem was solved for the fetch() property was adding a wait for the two promises, one for the main response and the other for the body of the response. Maybe it is related:

```
fetch(...)
.then ( response => Promise.all([response,response.json()]) )
.then ( ([response,body]) => { ... } )
```